# how to import a class in one .js file into another

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, import

I am trying to understand how to import a class in a .js file into another so that I can run an async function within the class imported.

```
//file called helloworld.js
class helloworld {
    async greetings(){
        console.log("hello world")

    }
}
export default helloworld;
```

I am attempting to use the async function called greetings in the code below

```
import helloworld from './helloworld';
console.log(helloworld.greetings)
```

It results in an error when I run

> node helloworld_import.js

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `helloworld` is a class so you need to instantiate first. Then only you can use its `methods`.

**2.** `greetings` is not a property, its an object so need to invoke/call/execute it will `()`.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-leaf-9inim?file=/src/index.js)

```
import helloworld from "./helloworld";

const obj = new helloworld();
obj.greetings();
```

If you'd like to access with the class name `helloworld`, make the function `greetings` static (For simplicity I've used in single js file, If you need you can import and export as per your need)

```js
class helloworld {
  static async greetings() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}

helloworld.greetings();
```